# Change the Orientation for UIView that is removed from the superview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

In my App, i have a single button and two Views, When i tapped the button, i removed the First View from the superview and add the second view on the superview as the subview. But the problem is that when i changed the device orientation from portrait to landscape, and then tapped the button, it will show the view in the  portrait view not in the landscape mode and vice versa. Here is the code which i am using.

```
    - (void)showFiles {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.25];

[UIView setAnimationTransition:([songTableView superview] ?
                                UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft : UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight)
                       forView:toggleButton cache:YES];

UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

if ((orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)) {
    [songTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 44.0f, 480.0f, 256.0f)];
}
else {
    [songTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 44.0f, 320.0f, 416.0f)];
}

if ([songTableView superview]) {
    [toggleButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"AudioPlayerAlbumInfo.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else {
    [toggleButton setImage:albumArtImageView.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

[UIView commitAnimations];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

[UIView setAnimationTransition:([songTableView superview] ?
                                UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft : UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight)
                       forView:self.view cache:YES];
if ([songTableView superview])
{
    albumArtImageView.image = albumArtImage;
    albumArtImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit; 
    albumArtImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    [songTableView removeFromSuperview];
    [gradientLayer removeFromSuperlayer];

    [self.view addSubview:uppercontrollsView];
    [self.view addSubview:lowercontrollsView];
}
else
{
    [albumArtImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"AudioPlayerTableBackground.png"]];
    albumArtImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill; 
    albumArtImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    [uppercontrollsView removeFromSuperview];
    [lowercontrollsView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:songTableView];

    [songTableView reloadData];
}

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

Comment: which ios are you targeting ?

Comment: btw. the way you do animations is deprecated and discouraged by now ;)
instead you should use [UIView animateWithDuration:...] blocks like described in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use willRotateToInterfaceOrientation method. When you change device orientation it will call..

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 

 {

 return YES;

 }

  -(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration

   {

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)) 

  {

  [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 52, 728, 617)];

  }
 else

{

[btn setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 52, 728, 617)];

}

    }
```

Comment: Dear Kalpesh, i want that the view should follow the device orientation. bcz when i removeOneView and addanotherView. the added view is in portrait view, while the device is in landscape view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle iOS 6, what you can do is :

If you're on view A, then store its InterfaceOrientation and then

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
  return lastInterfaceOrientation;
}
```